# I can import scipy in my command prompt but I get a DLL load fail when I run my script

Tags: python, numpy

Windows 7 
Python 2.7

When I import scipy in my command prompt, everything works as expected:

```
Python 2.7.12 |Anaconda 4.2.0 (32-bit)| (default, Jun 29 2016, 11:42:13)        [MSC v.
1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://anaconda.org
>>> from scipy.stats import norm
```

When I run a script, scipy has a DLL issue:

```
  from scipy.stats import norm
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\__init__.py", line 344, in <module>
  from .stats import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\stats.py", line 173, in <module>
  import scipy.special as special
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\special\__init__.py", line 636, in <module>
  from ._ufuncs import *
  ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: It means your system environment path is not set!

Comment: Do you have two Python installations, one from Anaconda and one from python.org?

Comment: Hmm the Anaconda install is new, but how would I force the system env to use the original python install and not look in the anaconda path?